# Rails mongoid tri-model relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, relationship

[image]

I have that relationship depicted above in blue, however, it prompts many errors e.g. no method error.

Would the EMBEDDED RELATIONS(in red) between A and C be OKay? given the two other relationships .

Besides, in the route file, should I nest B in A ?

Please advise and thanks.

```
class Trip
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name
  key :name

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :logs
end

class Log
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :content
  validates_presence_of :content
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :trips
  has_many :logs
end
```

The error:

```
NoMethodError in Trips#show

Showing /home/jason/apps/app/views/trips/show.html.haml where line #17 raised:

undefined method `logs_path' for #<#<Class:0x9b8a14c>:0x9d3251c>
```

The Controller:

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
   def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    @log = Log.new
    @logmsg = @trip.logs
  end
end

class LogsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @log = @trip.logs.build(params[:log])
    current_user.logs.build(params[:log])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @log.save
        format.html { redirect_to @log, notice: 'successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to trip_path(@trip) }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    I want an ajax destroy here, as the logs will only be shown in the Trips show page.
  end
end
```

The show - trips/show.html.haml:

```
= form_for @log do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :content
    = f.text_field :content
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Below is a route file excerpt:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :trips do
    resources :logs
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'should I nest B in A'?

Comment: I mean the controller settings. E.g. http://localhost:3000/A(controller)/B(controller)/

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot embed `ModalA` in `ModalC`, because `ModelB` will be unable to reference the embedded objects.

Embedded models are actually *inside* the parent document, not in a separate collection.

Comment: But I referenced the models as depicted by the blue hand-writings, that still doesn't work.Can you tell me how to relate the three of them?Thanks.

Comment: It would make it much easier if you could update your question to include your model code and the exact errors that you're getting.